# cannot load static files in django4

Tags: django, static, frontend, backend

i have folder structure in my django4 project like that:
firstsite/
firstsite/
women/
static/
women/
css/
style.css

and in template i load that style like that:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'your_app/css/style.css' %}">
```

and when i try to load but static files:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'your_app/css/style.css' %}">
```

it throws error:

> Refused to apply style from 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/your_app/css/style.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.

can you help me with that?

Comment: Have you used Django {% load static %} tag on top of your HTML templates?  Check further here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/howto/static-files/